# Identify Duplicates and Filter Unique Records From SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I've 3 tables in a SQL Server DB
table 1: Employee

```
GroupId |   EmployeeId  |   IsDuplicate
=======================================
    1   |       101     |       0
    1   |       102     |       1
    1   |       103     |       1
--------|---------------|--------------
    2   |       201     |       1
    2   |       202     |       0
--------|---------------|--------------
    3   |       301     |       1
    3   |       302     |       1
    3   |       303     |       0
---------------------------------------
```

table 2: Contacts

```
ContactId   |   ContactEmail    |   Name    |...
================================================
    11      |       c1@mail.com |   c1 x    |
    12      |       c2.mail.com |   c2 y    |
    13      |       c1.mail.com |   c1.x    |
    14      |       c3@mail.com |   c3.z    |
    15      |       c3@mail.com |   c3 z    |
------------|-------------------|-----------|
    21      |       d1@mail.com |   d1 a    |
    22      |       d2@mail.com |   d2 b    |
------------|-------------------|-----------|
    31      |       e1@mail.com |   e1 m    |
    32      |       e1@mail.com |   e1m     |
    33      |       e2@mail.com |   e2 n    |
--------------------------------------------
```

table 3: EmployeeContacts

```
EmployeeId  |   ContactId
=========================
    101     |       11
    101     |       12
    102     |       13
    102     |       14
    103     |       15
------------|------------
    201     |       21
    202     |       22
------------|------------
    301     |       31
    302     |       32
    303     |       33
-------------------------
```

table 1 has groups of employees that are pre-identified and grouped together as duplicates, and keeping one employee (`IsDuplicate=0`) of each group the rest will be deleted later.
Each employee has one or more contacts, each contact details are kept in a different 'Contacts' table and which employee has what contact is kept in a seperate 'EmployeeContacts' table.
This Contacts table has multiple coulmns and only email ids can be used to identify who are duplicate of others.

Problem Statement:
I need to write a script where I need to take the unique contacts of each group and roll it up to the active employee (`IsDuplicate=0`) of that group.
That is, from the 'Contacts' table I've to identify the duplicate contacts for each group of employees and the unique ones will be inserted in to the 'EmployeeContacts' table.
So the target result is:
table 3: EmployeeContacts

```
EmployeeId  |   ContactId
=========================
    101     |       11
    101     |       12
    101     |       14 -- <-- Unique contcat rolled up to the selected active employee 
    102     |       13
    102     |       14
    103     |       15
------------|------------
    201     |       21
    202     |       22
    202     |       21 -- <-- Unique contcat rolled up to the selected active employee 
------------|------------
    301     |       31
    302     |       32
    303     |       33 
    303     |       31 -- <-- Unique contcat rolled up to the selected active employee 
-------------------------
```

I was trying to approach problem like this:
I would join all 3 tables and take the contact email, group id, contact id and employee id in to a separate temp table and then using cursor i'll loop through this temp table and put the unique contact id in a separate temp table

```
SELECT GroupId, ec.EmployeeId, ec.ContactId, c.ContactEmail
INTO #Temp1
FROM EmployeeContacts ec
INNER JOIN Contacts c ON c.ContactId = ec.ContactId
INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.EmployeeId = ec.EmployeeId
ORDER BY GroupId, c.ContactEmail
```

So for `groupid=1`, the temp table would look like this

## Temp1

```
GroupId |   EmployeeId  |   ContactId   |   ContactEmail
========================================================
    1   |       101     |       11      |   c1@mail.com
    1   |       102     |       13      |   c1.mail.com
    1   |       101     |       12      |   c2.mail.com
    1   |       102     |       14      |   c3@mail.com
    1   |       103     |       15      |   c3@mail.com
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I am thinking to use a cursor to loop through this #Temp table per group and by comparing the 'ContactEmail' values of each contact I will identify the unique contacts and out them in to another temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp2
(
    ContactId INT,
    GroupId INT
)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT GroupId, ContactId, ContactEmail
FROM #Temp1

DECLARE @ContactEmail NVARCHAR(50), @GroupId INT, @ContactId INT;
DECLARE @CompareEmail NVARCHAR(50);

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @GroupId, @ContactId, @ContactEmail

SET @CompareEmail = '';

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    IF(@CompareEmail <>  @ContactEmail)
    BEGIN
        SET @CompareEmail = @ContactEmail
        INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES(@ContactId, @GroupId)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    INTO @GroupId, @ContactId, @ContactEmail
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

I have not run it yet, but I think this will give me #Temp2 table with unique Contact Id

## Temp2

```
GroupId |   ContactId
=====================
    1   |       11
    1   |       12
    1   |       14
---------------------
```

Now I know which employee is active per group and I can insert  the new contact id in the 'EmployeeContacts' table.

But this whole process seems a bit complex and time taking one. So is there a shorter or a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to get the desired result:

```
declare cur cursor fast_forward for select distinct GroupId from @employee
declare @groupid int, @employeeid int

open cur
fetch next from cur into @groupid

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    select @employeeid = EmployeeId from @employee where GroupId = @groupid and IsDuplicate = 0
    select e.EmployeeId, IsDuplicate, c.*
    into #temp
    from @employee e
    join @employeecontacts ec on ec.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    join @contacts c on c.ContactId = ec.ContactId
    where GroupId = @groupid

    ;with cte as
    (
        select @employeeid employeeid, t.ContactId, t.ContactEmail, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.ContactEmail order by  t.ContactId) rn--, c.ContactEmail as ce2
        from #temp t 
        left join (select EmployeeId, x.ContactId, ContactEmail from @employeecontacts x join @contacts c on c.ContactId = x.ContactId)ec 
        on ec.EmployeeId = @employeeid and ec.ContactEmail = t.ContactEmail
        where ec.ContactId is null
    )
    insert into @employeecontacts
    select employeeid, ContactId from cte where rn = 1

    drop table if exists #temp
    fetch next from cur into @groupid
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8105726cb695250fc802b6f72794f70b)**.

Comment: Thanks a Ton! This is excellent...I'm trying to wrap my head around it but I think this is going to work as the fiddle link seals any doubt.